# WCF Client call is getting ThreadAbortedException

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF client which calls a service, currently we have set the timeout to 2 mins.

Once the timeout is reached we are handling it in the catch.

In catch we are checking whether the connection is faulted or not, if it is faulted we are creating a new client and then we are calling the request again, we are doing this for 3 times. Once the retry count is reached we are closing the client.

The code looks like

```
public object CallWebMethod(string webMethodName, oject Request)`
{
    response = Client.GetData(request);
}

Catch (Exception ex)
{
    if(retry<4)
    {
        if(Client!=null && Client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
       {
            Client = new Client();
        }
        response = CallWebMethod(webmethodname, request);
    }
}

finally
{
  if(Client!=null)
  {
     Client.Close();
  }
}
```

We are getting Thread abort exception once in a while, Here my question is what happens if the first response comes while executing the second request?

I also noticed that we are getting subsequent request even before the specified time outs.

I am new to asking a question even though I have used this site to full effect in getting answer. Please help :)

Comment: Pradeep, I don't think the approach you're taking (recursing method calls to a wcf web service) is what you want to be doing. First, if the client times out and the web service connection is faulted, something catastrophic happened on the host, so just spinning up a new request isn't going to help matters. You'd be better off putting in a minute or two delay between requests to give the web service time to recover from whatever happened. You might also use something simple like a ping request/response to the web service to ensure that it's actually running before hitting it again.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the quick response. I understand the points you are referring to but I need to know when will the exception Thread Abort occurs is it when the response from the first request overlap with the second request? How would .Net handle that situation?

Right now I am handling this by adding 
`Client.Abort();`
`Client = new Client();`

before making a new call, this change is also futile so far.

Comment: I guess my point is that, if the request is the same, the clients shouldn't have overlapping requests. They should run in serial, not parallel, unless the requests are different.

Comment: Ok Thanks Brian, that helped me.. I am also happy that I got the solution, the Thread Abort was due to Http timeout exception which was set to 110 seconds by default, once I got that updated, it is working like charm :)